# Qt: Cannot execute '': The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: qt, qt-creator, privileges

I am not able to run the application the Qt creator. It complains the following error:

Cannot execute '': The requested operation requires elevation

My .exe file has a Windows administrator shield symbol on it. Do I need to make a project settings changes? I am extensively using Qt File library for doing some file operations.

Comment: What's your executable's file name? Without an embedded manifest, windows tries to be smart and wants to run executables with "install", "update", "setup" etc. in the file name as administrator.

Comment: @Frank You got it, I had my .exe named Updater.exe. When I renamed the application it works fine. Please post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's your executable's file name? Without an embedded manifest, windows tries to be smart and wants to run executables with "install", "update", "setup", "patch", etc. in the file name as administrator.  It even checks for those names within words such as "autoupdate".

The problem is that qmake/mingw doesn't embed those manifests, while MSVC does. If someone has a clean solution to that problem, I'd be interested to learn about it.

Comment: With [QMAKE_LFLAGS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags) ,  with both Qt kits MSVC as well as MinGW, .. [Syntax example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467663/while-click-run-in-my-project-i-am-getting-failed-to-start-program-path-or-per?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

If application you develop require administrator privileges, you cannot simply run it from Qt creator, started under non privileged  account.

You can **run your Qt creator as Administrtor**.

Or you can start your application from QtCreator using `runas` utility.
But in this case you would not be able to see debug output in QtCreator console window and debug application.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the exe file has some words (update, patch, ...), the Windows UAC ask for admin privilegies. The only solution is that the project generates an exe without these words.

See this: [Qt Creator create exes with admin privilegies](https://forum.qt.io/topic/96466/qt-creator-create-exes-with-admin-privilegies)