# While click run in my project i am getting "Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?"

Tags: qt

While click run on my project in qt creator

```
" Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?"

11:02:18: Starting C:\V6\Filename2.0\release\Filename.exe...
11:02:18: Failed to start program. Path or permissaions wrong?
11:02:18: C:/V6/Filename2.0/release/Filename.exe exited with code -1
11:02:18: The process failed to start. Either the invoked program "C:/V6/Filename2.0/release/Filename2.exe" is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information (Qt and Qt Creator version, OS version - I assume it's windows) it's difficult to formulate a sensible hypothesis, however, off the top of my head some things you might try:

1. are you sure there's not another Filename.exe running? if there is QtCreator cannot create a new executable replacing current one that is in use
2. maybe windows holds some lock on that particular file / folder, it might be worth checking with tools like [mst isusedby](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/IsUsedBy.shtml)
3. try closing QtCreator / rebooting to clean any stale locks on that folder
4. in the projects section choose another folder for shadow building and see if the executable can be created there.

Comment: With reference to above 4 points, we tried everything and still the same issue persists. 

QT and QT Creator 4.6.2 is in use, OS version is Windows 10

Comment: was the executable created in the first place? what compiler are you using? have you managed at all to create a running piece of code? does the example run on your installation?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to executable file name , as pointed out in this answer :   [Qt: Cannot execute '': The requested operation requires elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215934/qt-cannot-execute-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation)  that shows another error message, this happens if executable file name contains or ends with  "*install*", "*update*", "*setup*", "*patch*".

On the other hand, its possible to explicitly set (access level) *manifist* in the `.pro`  with Admin privileges required:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:\"level=\'requireAdministrator\' uiAccess=\'false\'\"
```

Or, to set access for current user:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:\"level=\'asInvoker\' uiAccess=\'false\'\"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I have had this issue, caused by a target flag set as :

```
TARGET = runme.exe
```

in my .pro file.

Removing the extension,and changing it to just :

```
TARGET = runme
```

has solved this issue for me.